# WMI recursive remote registry read

Tags: c#, recursion, registry, wmi

I am trying to list a remote registry folder on a domain. I was able to list keys but not recursively using WMI or OpenRemoteBaseKey.
I would like to get Keyname, Values, Type on registry folders and subfolders for x32 & x64, preferably using WMI as I need other informations on clients.

Here is my code actually but needs to be improved :

```
            foreach (string strComputer in arrComputers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
                Console.WriteLine("  Computer: " + strComputer);
                Console.WriteLine("==========================================");

                ManagementClass classInstance = 
                    new ManagementClass("\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\DEFAULT", 
                    "StdRegProv", null);

                ManagementBaseObject inParams = 
                    classInstance.GetMethodParameters("EnumValues");

                inParams["sSubKeyName"] =  "SOFTWARE\\IPS";

                ManagementBaseObject outParams = 
                    classInstance.InvokeMethod("EnumValues", inParams, null);

                Console.WriteLine("Out parameters:");
                Console.WriteLine("ReturnValue: " + outParams["ReturnValue"]);
                Console.WriteLine("sNames: " + outParams["sNames"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Types: " + outParams["Types"]);
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any recursion in your code.
Here is an example.  ParseKey will dump the values using 'ParseChildValues' before recursing on all child subkeys.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
...

/// <summary>
/// This method returns a list of registry values from a given key in .reg format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">Registry key from which to obtain values.</param>
/// <returns>A CR-separated list of all the registry values for a given key.</returns>
private static string ParseChildValues(RegistryKey key)
{
    if (key.IsNull())
        return string.Empty;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(string val in key.GetValueNames())
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}=\"{1}\"", string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) ? "@" : val, key.GetValue(val));
        sb.AppendLine();
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

/// <summary>
/// Parses the SubKeys of a given RegistryKey.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">A registry key</param>
/// <returns>Lots of important data!</returns>
private static string ParseKey(RegistryKey key)
{
    if (key.IsNull())
        return string.Empty;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendFormat("[{0}]", key.Name);
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.Append(ParseChildValues(key));
    foreach (var subKey in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        sb.Append(ParseKey(key.OpenSubKey(subKey)));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Dump the contents of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*
    Console.WriteLine("Getting the contents of HKCR\\* on the local machine");
    RegistryKey localHKCR = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("*", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
    Console.WriteLine(ParseKey(localHKCR));

    // Dump the contents of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\* on a remote machine.
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Getting the contents of HKCR\\* via OpenRemoteBaseKey");
    RegistryKey remoteHKCR = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, "MACHINENAME");
    Console.WriteLine(ParseKey(remoteHKCR.OpenSubKey("*", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)));
}
```